# Java's XJC like tool in Python

Tags: python, xml-parsing, xjc

Is there a equivalent tool in python like XJC? XJC takes a schema and generates Java classes. One can populate a in-memory data-structure using these classes. No need to write them by hand.

Answer (score 1):

You can try PyXB: http://pyxb.sourceforge.net

> PyXB (“pixbee”) is a pure Python package that generates Python source code for classes that correspond to data structures defined by XMLSchema.